# Does S/4HANA Cloud SDK support obtaining metadata instead of the actual entities for OData?

Tags: s4sdk

I am trying to obtain the metadata to an OData service endpoint. I am not interested in the entities themselves, but the metadata tethering to this particular entity.

I saw there is a `useMetadata(Boolean boolean)` method, but it is set to `true` by default and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Does the cloud connectivity sdk support this feature?

The library I am currently using is `com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQueryBuilder`.

**EDIT:**
The use case is that my team is currently developing an app to examine and automate the data migration process from a provider to S/4HANA. The app will prompt the user to make remedying fixes if the configuration it obtains from the metadata shows discrepancies from our best practice and in turn, will probably cause trouble in the data replication process. This said configuration is exposed through metadata instead of the entities from the OData API.

**For instance**: If a customer would like to migrate the `FOCustomer` records to S/4HANA, he or she may want to set the `MaxLength` of the `FormalName` property to `12`, or the data integrity might be compromised in the destination system. We are not interested in the customer entries, or what is actually in `FormalName`, but the configuration the customer set in the source system, which is exposed in the OData API as a metadata document entry like:

`<Property Name="name_defaultValue" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" sap:required="false" sap:creatable="true" sap:updatable="true" sap:upsertable="true" sap:visible="true" sap:sortable="true" sap:filterable="true" MaxLength="32" sap:label="Name"></Property>`

In this case, `MaxLength` is set as `32` instead of `12` which would be logged and referred to the customer for further action.

We used Olingo for this purpose before. Now we are evaluating S/4SDK since it seemingly provides a more streamlined solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do and what you need the metadata for?

Comment: @Benjamin I have added a bit more details to my use case. Hope it clears things up a bit. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `ODataQueryBuilder` itself does not support standalone metadata retrieval. The metadata is only used under the hood, therefore `useMetadata()` does not help you for your use case.

However, given that you have setup the destination from which you want to retrieve the metadata, you could do the following (my destination is named `ErpQueryEndpoint` in this example):

```
final String destinationUriString = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("ErpQueryEndpoint").getUri().toString();
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient("ErpQueryEndpoint");
final URI uri = new URI(destinationUriString + "/sap/opu/odata/sap/NAME_OF_THE_API/$metadata");
final HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
```

This should allow you to retrieve the metadata in XML format. You'd still need to parse it using Olingo, though.

Currently we do not plan to support standalone metadata retrieval.
However, if you want, you can open an issue on our [public GitHub page](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/issues) so we may consider this in the future.

Let me know if this answers your questions or if you have further questions!

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my doubt! I'm kind of disappointed to hear this, as metadata retrieval is useful in our scenario, and I tend to believe we are not the marginal use case. I will raise a feature request in the link as instructed.

Comment: By the way, regarding destination, is enabling destination in non-trial subaccounts on CF in timeline? Thank you!

Comment: @ChuningSong: The destination service on SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry is already available as beta right now ([help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/7e306250e08340f89d6c103e28840f30.html)). It is also already supported by the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK.

Comment: @HenningHeitkötter There's a `NOTE` on the page saying, "This is a beta feature available on SAP Cloud Platform for subaccounts in trial accounts." Hence my question. I failed to subscribe and create a `destination` service in the cockpit.